# Very long time of loading img assets in next.js app

Tags: image, optimization, next.js

Recently I was working on next.js project and I run for one issue which I'm struggling a lot and I can't find any solution.

When I'm checking the app on vercel/netlify servers, images are loading very very slow. I'm using `next/image`.

My files are compressed in webp format. Also I'm storing them in CDN.
I was setting parameters like `priority='true'`, `loading='eager'` and nothing accelerated the loading time. Average I'm waiting about 2-3 seconds. I felt like using classic `img` tag was a little bit faster.

Did any of you have same issue and maybe you have solution?
Thanks